# In Rails, using Cancancan/Will_Paginate how can I only show navigation links that user's can read?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, cancancan

I am using both `cancancan` and `will_paginate`.  Certain users have the ability to read certain reports defined by the following block.

**Ability.rb**

```
can :read, Report do |report|
  if report.is_pro?
    if (8..12).include? Time.now.month
      (report.created_at.year != Time.now.year) || (report.author_id == user.id)
    elsif (1..4).include? Time.now.month
      (report.created_at.year < Time.now.year-1) || (report.author_id == user.id)
    else
      true
    end
  end
end
```

However, when using the pagination links on a given page like below, the restriction works and users can only see the reports that are able to but, the will_paginate links show up as if all the reports are visible.

**users_controller.html.erb**

```
@reports = Report.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)
```

**report_activity.html.erb**

```
<% @reports.each do |report| %>
  <% if can? :read, report %>
    <% render 'user_report', report: report %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= will_paginate @reports %>
```

I did find a link that mentions using the method `accessible_by(current_ability)` in my ActiveQuery.  But this means I need to rewrite my `Cancancan` Ability block shown above into a hash.  I'm not sure how to do my current logic as a hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was the following.  Hopefully this helps someone else, but basically it was just rethinking how this should be setup I believe...

```
if (8..12).include?(Time.now.month) # Is the current month in Aug thru Dec?
  # Allowed to read reports that are before August of the current year
  can :read, Report, "((year(created_at) <> #{Time.now.year}) AND (month(created_at) >= 8)) OR reports.author_id = #{user.id}"

elsif (1..4).include?(Time.now.month) # Is the current month in Jan thru April?
  # Allowed to read reports that are before August of the previous year
  can :read, Report, "(year(created_at) < #{Time.now.year-1}) AND (month(created_at) <= 7) OR reports.author_id = #{user.id}"

else # or is it in May to July... wdgaf!
  can :read, Report, :all
end
```